# For loop only works for the first element

Tags: javascript, html, function, loops, for-loop

Hey my for loop only works for the first element of first div, no matter what div I click and I got an error

> faq.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined.
> I've tried to declare **var div** before loop or I made a nested loop.

```js
var i;
for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
  var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[i];
  p.style.display = "none";

}

function Show() {

for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++){
   var div = document.getElementsByClassName('faq-box')[j];
   if(div.getElementsByTagName('p')[j].style.display == "none") {
     div.getElementsByTagName('p')[j].style.display = "block";
   }
   else {
     div.getElementsByTagName('p')[j].style.display = "none";
   }
}
}
```

```html
  <h2>FAQ</h2>
    <div class="faq-box">
      <h4 onclick="Show()">How many team members can I invite?</h4>
      <p>You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on
      team members for the Premium plan.</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="faq-box">
      <h4 onclick="Show()"> What is the maximum file upload size?</h4>
      <p class="p">No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your allotted storage space.</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="faq-box">
      <h4 onclick="Show()">How do I reset my password?</h4>
      <p class="p">You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on
      team members for the Premium plan.</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
```

Comment: you have only 3 `<p>` but you are iterating 4 times `i <= 3` last one gives error, use `i<3`

also instead of hard coded values you can better use
`for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('p').length; i++){ `

Comment: There are only 3 `p` tags, so accessing the 4th will give you `undefined`. It's best not to hardcode the number at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that might help you work in the right direction without hardcoding!

```js
for (let el of document.getElementsByTagName('p')) {
  el.style.display = "none";

}

function Show(el) {
   el = el.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
   if (el.style.display == "none") {
     el.style.display = "block";
   } else {
     el.style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

```html
<h2>FAQ</h2>
    <div class="faq-box">
      <h4 onclick="Show(this)">How many team members can I invite?</h4>
      <p>You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on
      team members for the Premium plan.</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="faq-box">
      <h4 onclick="Show(this)"> What is the maximum file upload size?</h4>
      <p class="p">No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your allotted storage space.</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="faq-box">
      <h4 onclick="Show(this)">How do I reset my password?</h4>
      <p class="p">You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on
      team members for the Premium plan.</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
```